# Verifying data type during parsing (string to int) in c++

Tags: c++, validation

I'm trying to test the casting of a string to an integer to make sure the data in the string is actually data that belongs in an integer. (ex. the user input '!!!!' so I don't want it going to the int).

The problem I'm having is I want to be able to throw an error somehow right after I detect that the conversion can't happen. The reason I want to test it during the cast or right after is because I need the input from the user to first go to a string.

I first tried doing "option 1" and I noticed that some sort of a debug error pops up and it doesn't let me throw my own and show a more user friendly error.

I then am trying option 2 (thinking I could wrap the verify right around the cast) but while I'm Watching the variable type, it passes option 2 even though it's showing as a string and my code doesnt seem to catch that it's not an int, and therefore throw my error

I would only use one of the two options and note both obviously. I just put both of my e

```
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
string employeeNumber;
string hoursWorked;
int newEmployeeNumber;


cout << "What is your employee number?" << endl;
cin >> employeeNumber;

//CONVERT AND VERIFY CAST/CONVERSION OCCURRED SUCCESSFULLY
//IF NOT (ex. user entered '!!!' so it shouldnt be able to cast to int..
//THEN THROW MY ERROR


//option 1
newEmployeeNumber = stoi(employeeNumber);
throw MyErrorThatDoesntGetReached("notan int");
//(will throw its own error right there and I can't let it throw mine after


//option 2
if (typeid(stoi(employeeNumber)) != typeid(int) )
            throw Exception("data in file is CORRUPT");



}
```

Comment: Why not declaring `employeeNumber` an `int` in the first plae ?

Comment: Check the result of the input operation to an `int`. If you need to check the entire string, calling `stoi` with one parameter isn't going to cut it.

Comment: catch stoi's exception, throw your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sleeper's idea isn't bad at all. Alternatively though, we could just catch the exception that `std::stoi()` throws on invalid inputs:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string employeeNumber;
    string hoursWorked;
    int newEmployeeNumber;

    cout << "What is your employee number?" << endl;
    cin >> employeeNumber;

    try {
        newEmployeeNumber = stoi(employeeNumber);
    } catch (std::invalid_argument const & e) {
        throw MyException("The input couldn't be parsed as a number");
    } catch (std::out_of_range const & e) {
        throw MyException("the input was not in the range of numbers supported by this type");
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I have to use std::invalid_argument const & e in the catch? Could I just have my own exception class I create and do the try, and then just have catch(MyException class e){ do stuff}?

Comment: Actually, answers this - how could I know in the future what exception it is that I need to catch for other future function errors I might get? Im a newbie and I wouldn't have known to put std::invalid_argumet const & e in to catch

Comment: @user3389343: Check the documentation of the functions you are calling. For [`std::stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), the documentation reports that it can throw either of those two exceptions.

Comment: @user3389343: And for the first part, you can use your own exception type. That's what I've shown here. `std::stoi()` will throw one of those 2 exceptions, and then you can wrap them in your own exception type and rethrow that.

Answer (score 0):

For testing a value I offer regular expression:

```
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

bool isNumber( string val );

void main() {

    string employeeNumber;
    string hoursWorked;
    int newEmployeeNumber;


    cout << "What is your employee number?" << endl;
    cin >> employeeNumber;

    if ( isNumber( employeeNumber ) ) {
        newEmployeeNumber = stoi(employeeNumber);

        cout << "is number\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "is not number\n";
    }

    getch();
}

bool isNumber( const string val ) {
    std::string templ("\\d*");

    if ( regex_match( val, std::regex(templ) ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

UPDATE:
Other variant of function IsNumber:

```
bool isNumber( const string val ) {

    for( int i = 0; i < val.length(); i++ ) {

        if ( !isdigit( val[i] ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```